# How can I get the top two rows using max condition?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I get the top 2 rows returned in this query?

```
select nomeClube 'Clube', count(Contrato_id_clube) 'NContratos'
from clube, contrato
where (id_clube= Contrato_id_clube)
group by nomeClube
order by count(Contrato_id_clube) desc
```

[image: query results]

Comment: try the limit option

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you want *all* groups having the maximum count and your example just happens to have two such rows.

```
select nomeClube 'Clube', count(Contrato_id_clube) 'NContratos'
from clube inner join contrato on id_clube = Contrato_id_clube
group by nomeClube
having count(Contrato_id_club) = (
    select max(c)
    from (
        select count(Contrato_id_clube) c
        from clube inner join contrato on id_clube = Contrato_id_clube
        group by nomeClube
    ) t
)
```

The inner join inside the nested query may not be necessary but since you didn't specify the relationship between the tables I've duplicated the entire query there.

Answer (score -1):

you should put it in an inner select and get top records:

```
select * from (
select nomeClube 'Clube', count(Contrato_id_clube) 'NContratos'
from clube, contrato
where (id_clube= Contrato_id_clube)
group by nomeClube
order by count(Contrato_id_clube) desc )
limit 2
```